# Display inherited methods in NetBeans

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans

I have an interface with default methods some layers of abstract classes that build upon each other and a class that does the actual work. Now I would like to see all the methods in their top-most implementation in a single view.

I have this problem more then once and in different projects, so I'm looking for a general solution. I hope that there is some option to toggle this display, but would be willing to try plugins that do this.

Having a 'Navigator' Style Window that lists the methods in a Tree View would be fine as well, then I can directly click through the proper methods.

Example:

```
public interface IFoo {
    String getName();
    String getVersion();
    default String getDefaultVersion() {
        return "1.0.0";
    }
    default String getDefaultGroup() {
        return "de.fuchs.sample";
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    protected String getNameWithVersion() {
        return getName() + " " + getVersion();
    }
    protected String getDefaultVersion() {
        return "8.8.8";
    }
}

public class ConcreteFoo {
    public String getName() {
        return "Foo";
    }
    public String getVersion() {
        return getDefaultVersion();
    }
}
```

Now I would like to have a display like this:

```
public class ConcreteFoo {
    public String getName() {
        return "Foo";
    }
    public String getVersion() {
        return getDefaultVersion();
    }

    // INHERITED FROM AbstractFoo:
    protected String getNameWithVersion() {
        return getName() + " " + getVersion();
    }
    protected String getDefaultVersion() {
        return "8.8.8";
    }

    // INHERITED FROM IFoo
    String getDefaultGroup() {
        return "de.fuchs.sample";
    }
```

}

Its fine if the 'INHERITED' sections don't properly display line numbers, etc. and I don't need to have writing capabilities there.

Is there a way to get this display?

Comment: You can't get that into the source code window. The editor is based on Java source files and you can't have the inherited methods in the derived class (because they are in a different file). The Navigator **will** show inherited methods.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sounds like an answer, care to post it as such? (please include the information that you have to toggle the "Navigator -> Filter -> Show Inherited Members" By default it did not show this to me and I just found out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution for the editor, but the **Navigator** has the Option:

In Navigator, **right click** on an empty area. 
Select: Filters -> Show Inherited Members

Alternatively click the icon on the bottom of the screen.

A screenshot from my Netbeans 8.2 EE edition:

[image: Netbeans Navigator with highlighted Show Inherited Icon]

Comment: It's missing in version 8. Possible?

Comment: @nbrogi In my version 8 it is present.

Comment: Really? I'm using the Mac version and it's not there. Could you take a screenshot to show me how you activate it?

Comment: @nbrogi There you go, I just downloaded NetBeans to this workstation and I see why my description was insufficient.

Comment: Sorry..? Is there an image in your comment? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: ...apologies, I see the image in your answer and I guess that's what you were referring to. Damn, I don't know, it's not there in 8.2 on Mac for PHP files.

Comment: @nbrogi I didn't test it for PHP, I only use NetBeans for Java

Comment: Gotcha. It's got to be that it's not enabled for PHP. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You could see it from the top line in Navigator. The "::" denotes inheritance and ":" denotes implementation.

Comment: That's not what I want. I already know the super class, but I want to see its methods.